# Tests failed, protractor exited with code: 1 - using Internet explorer

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I have a angularJS project and I'm executing e2e protractor test using the following grunt commandg:

> grunt test:e2e

I put multiCapabilities for chrome, firefox and internet explorer. My protractor.conf.js file is below:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    exports.config = {
        // Files that contains e2e tests
        specs: ['*.js'],

        // All browser that will be used on e2d tests
        multiCapabilities: [{
            'browserName': 'chrome'
        }, {
            'browserName': 'firefox'
        }, {
            'browserName': 'internet explorer'
        }],

        // Application's url
        baseUrl: 'http://localhost:9001/app/view/',

        // Test framework
        framework: 'jasmine'
    };
})();
```

But it got error and the log error message is:

```
c:\REPOSITORIOS\OficinaTA\site>grunt test:e2e
Running "selenium_start" task
seleniumrc webdriver ready on 127.0.0.1:4444

Running "connect:test" (connect) task
Started connect web server on http://localhost:9001

Running "protractor:e2e" (protractor) task
[launcher] Running 3 instances of WebDriver

------------------------------------
[internet explorer #3] PID: 14484
[internet explorer #3] Starting selenium standalone server...
[internet explorer #3] Selenium standalone server started at http://10.10.6.26:5
8941/wd/hub
[internet explorer #3]
[internet explorer #3] c:\REPOSITORIOS\OficinaTA\site\node_modules\protractor\no
de_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:108
[internet explorer #3]   var template = new Error(this.message);
[internet explorer #3]                  ^
[internet explorer #3] UnknownError: Unexpected error launching Internet Explore
r. Protected Mode settings are not the same for all zones. Enable Protected Mode
 must be set to the same value (enabled or disabled) for all zones. (WARNING: Th
e server did not provide any stacktrace information)
[internet explorer #3] Command duration or timeout: 2.13 seconds
[internet explorer #3] Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time:
 '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
[internet explorer #3] System info: host: 'DSES026', ip: '10.10.6.26', os.name:
'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_65'
[internet explorer #3] Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDrive
r
[internet explorer #3]     at new bot.Error (c:\REPOSITORIOS\OficinaTA\site\node
_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:108:18)
[internet explorer #3]     at Object.bot.response.checkResponse (c:\REPOSITORIOS
\OficinaTA\site\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atom
s\response.js:109:9)
[internet explorer #3]     at c:\REPOSITORIOS\OficinaTA\site\node_modules\protra
ctor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:160:24
[internet explorer #3]     at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (c
:/REPOSITORIOS/OficinaTA/site/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webd
river/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:1857:20)
[internet explorer #3]     at [object Object].goog.defineClass.notify (c:/REPOSI
TORIOS/OficinaTA/site/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/li
b/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:2448:25)
[internet explorer #3]     at [object Object].promise.Promise.notify_ (c:/REPOSI
TORIOS/OficinaTA/site/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/li
b/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:564:12)
[internet explorer #3]     at Array.forEach (native)
[internet explorer #3]     at [object Object].promise.Promise.notifyAll_ (c:/REP
OSITORIOS/OficinaTA/site/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver
/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:553:15)
[internet explorer #3]     at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (c:\REPOSITORIOS\O
ficinaTA\site\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\a
sync\run.js:130:15)
[internet explorer #3]     at process._tickCallback (node.js:366:9)
[internet explorer #3] From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
[internet explorer #3]     at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.acquireSession_ (c:\R
EPOSITORIOS\OficinaTA\site\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriv
er\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:157:22)
[internet explorer #3]     at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.createSession (c:\REP
OSITORIOS\OficinaTA\site\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver
\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:131:30)
[internet explorer #3]     at [object Object].Builder.build (c:\REPOSITORIOS\Ofi
cinaTA\site\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\builder.js:4
45:22)
[internet explorer #3]     at [object Object].DriverProvider.getNewDriver (c:\RE
POSITORIOS\OficinaTA\site\node_modules\protractor\lib\driverProviders\driverProv
ider.js:38:7)
[internet explorer #3]     at [object Object].Runner.createBrowser (c:\REPOSITOR
IOS\OficinaTA\site\node_modules\protractor\lib\runner.js:182:37)
[internet explorer #3]     at c:\REPOSITORIOS\OficinaTA\site\node_modules\protra
ctor\lib\runner.js:263:21
[internet explorer #3]     at _fulfilled (c:\REPOSITORIOS\OficinaTA\site\node_mo
dules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:797:54)
[internet explorer #3]     at self.promiseDispatch.done (c:\REPOSITORIOS\Oficina
TA\site\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:826:30)
[internet explorer #3]     at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (c:\REPOSITORIOS\O
ficinaTA\site\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:759:13)
[internet explorer #3]     at c:\REPOSITORIOS\OficinaTA\site\node_modules\protra
ctor\node_modules\q\q.js:573:44

[launcher] Runner process exited unexpectedly with error code: 1
[launcher] 2 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
.
------------------------------------
[chrome #1] PID: 14752
[chrome #1] Starting selenium standalone server...
[chrome #1] Selenium standalone server started at http://10.10.6.26:64609/wd/hub

[chrome #1] .
[chrome #1]
[chrome #1] Finished in 4.893 seconds
[chrome #1] 1 test, 0 assertions, 0 failures
[chrome #1]
[chrome #1] Shutting down selenium standalone server.

[launcher] 1 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
.
------------------------------------
[firefox #2] PID: 6572
[firefox #2] Starting selenium standalone server...
[firefox #2] Selenium standalone server started at http://10.10.6.26:61342/wd/hu
b
[firefox #2] .
[firefox #2]
[firefox #2] Finished in 1.03 seconds
[firefox #2] 1 test, 0 assertions, 0 failures
[firefox #2]
[firefox #2] Shutting down selenium standalone server.

[launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[launcher] internet explorer #3 failed with exit code: 1
[launcher] chrome #1 passed
[launcher] firefox #2 passed
[launcher] overall: 1 process(es) failed to complete
[launcher] Process exited with error code 100
>>
Warning: Tests failed, protractor exited with code: 100 Use --force to continue.


Aborted due to warnings.
```

I don't know if I'm forgot to install anything or update anything to it works.

Comment: Sorry for the silly question, under which OS are you?

Comment: if you are running your tests against local machine, I think you need to previously install iedriver like this: `./node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update --ie32` hope this helps